# Get the title of a webpage using HttpWebRequest

Tags: html, vb.net, httpwebrequest, title

I am trying to get the text in the title tag on a website using `HttpWebRequest` in VB.Net.

Is it possible to retrieve the text with `HttpWebRequest` and/or `HttpWebResponse`?

Comment: post the code you have so far

Comment: All of the code that I have so far does not work, I honestly do not know where to start with this code.

Answer (score 2):

The `HttpWebRequest` classes are about sending HTTP requests.
They don't know anything about HTML.

Instead, you need to use an HTML parser, such as HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction of where I can obtain or use one?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at webclient.DownloadString. This should retrieve your webpage as a string within which you can locate the title tags.